a question on functional inequalities
enter image description here
Hello I am new to Stack exchange don't know how to use it but here's this question on functions I don't understand how to approach, help will be really appreciated

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is the answer option A??

Solve it using the first principle
